# Adding onclick function to Select2 tags in multiple select mode

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to get Select2 to return the value of an option when the tag itself is clicked on. The HTML itself doesn't seem to have any reference to the actual value. Is there anyway to do this? Thanks a lot!

```
<select id="teachers">
    <option value="1">Teacher Name 1</option>
    <option value="2">Teacher Name 2</option>
    <option value="3">Teacher Name 3</option>
</select>

$("#teachers").select2({
    placeholder:"Select teachers", 
    width:"resolve"

});



$("#teachers").select2("container").on("click", ".select2-search-choice", function() {

        console.log($("#teachers").select2("container").find(".select2-search-choice"));
});
```

The above returns the correct object, but there is no way to reference it to the original value in the select select tag.

Comment: where is your tried code ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try the following code

```
$("#teachers").select2({
placeholder: "Select teachers",
width: "resolve",
formatSelection: function(term) {
    return "<a href='#' onclick=javascript:alert('"+term.id+"')>"+term.text+"</a>";
}});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/406/)

Comment: It does not work in select2 ver 4.0.1. They renamed "formatSelection" into "templateSelection" and it does NOT support html elements any more. :(